# how to look 'n' elements ahead while iterating through java list?

Tags: java, list, iteration

I've a linked list with some elements.

```
 { (?i), \\d+, \\., \\d+, (?i), \\d+, \\. }
```

Now, while iterating, I need to find out if three consecutive values are `"\\d+", "\\.", "\\d+"`, if yes, I need to merge them into one node with value `"\\d+\\.\\d+"`. So, my previous list should look like the below after the said operation.

```
{(?i), \\d+\\.\\d+, (?i), \\d+, \\.}
```

But, as java doesn't expose linked list's internal node class there is no way for me to look ahead more than one node at a time. I could get it working with the following code, but it looks ugly to me. I'm wondering if there is any clean way of achieving the same.

```
LinkedList<String> l = new LinkedList<>(); //this can be ArrayList aswell. 
l.add("(?i)");
l.add("\\d+");
l.add("\\.");
l.add("\\d+");
l.add("(?i)");
l.add("\\d+");
l.add("\\.");
System.out.println(l.toString());
List<Integer> indexesToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    int j = i;
    if ("\\d+".equals(l.get(j))) {
        j++;
        if (j < l.size() && "\\.".equals(l.get(j))) {
            j++;
            if (j < l.size() && "\\d+".equals(l.get(j))) {
                l.set(i, "\\d+\\.\\d+");
                indexesToBeRemoved.add(j);
                indexesToBeRemoved.add(--j);
            }
        }

    }
}

for (int i : indexesToBeRemoved) {
    l.remove(i);
}

System.out.println(l.toString());

O/P:
[(?i), \d+, \., \d+, (?i), \d+, \.]
[(?i), \d+\.\d+, (?i), \d+, \.]
```

Comment: Is there no option of using ArrayList ? Because there you go with indexing

Comment: @SacJn Makes no difference. LinkedList also has Indexing.

Comment: Yes it has indexing but not efficient as ArrayList. So any operation on LinkedList consumes much more time than its counter part

Comment: @SacJn Yes I knew that. But your previous comment was ambiguous in a way that LinkedList didn't have indexing.

Comment: There I meant that even if you could get an element from linkedList by calling `get(index)` still that is not true use of indexes in true sense. Anyway written in short could sound ambiguous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`List.subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) is your friend, use it.

```
 List<String> pattern = Arrays.asList("\\d+", "\\.", "\\d+");
 for(int i=0; i<=l.size()-pattern.size(); i++) {
     List<String> subList = l.subList(i, i+pattern.size());
     if(subList.equals(pattern)) {
         subList.clear();
         subList.add("\\d+\\.\\d+");
     }
 }
 System.out.println(l);
```

Comment: I really like this solution but if you can change the hardcoded things like: `i<l.size()-2` to `i<=l.size() - pattern.size()`, `l.subList(i, i+3)` to `l.subList(i, i + pattern.size())` and to be really generic instead of `subList.add("\\d+\\.\\d+")` use `subList.add(String.join("", pattern))`

Comment: @Tagir Valeev. Genius. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Flown, pattern.size() - agreed, edited. `String.join` is Java-8 feature (current solution is Java-5 compatible) and in generic case it's probably not always should be replaced with joined pattern list, thus I'd leave this part as is.

Comment: @TagirValeev Agreed. Missed that is a Java 8 feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you are tied to using a LinkedList, you want to use an iterator rather than indexing, because get(n) is a O(n) operation. Since you want to be able to go backwards, you have to get a ListIterator from the listIterator() function.

```
for(ListIterator<String> i = l.listIterator(); i.hasNext();){
    String element = i.next();
    if(element.equals("\\d+") && i.hasNext()) {
       if(i.next().equals("\\.") && i.hasNext()) {
           if(i.next().equals("\\d+")) {
               i.remove();
               i.previous();
               i.remove();
               i.previous();
               i.set("\\d+\\.\\d+");
           } else {
               i.previous();
               i.previous();
           }
        } else {
            i.previous();
        }
    }
}
```

This can probably be cleaned up and made more general, but ListIterator is the tool you should use when working with linked lists.

Comment: Actually, I'm OK with Arraylist aswell. But, yeah, for LinkedList your answer makes more sense.